# spring security intercept url pattern is not working when url contains #

Tags: xml, spring, url, spring-boot

My url is

> //localhost:8080/server/#/view/3

and

> //localhost:8080/server/#/create

(# is present in the url by default as i am using routing from angularjs)

I want to assign some authority for the below urls, so i used the below URL patterns

```
security:intercept-url pattern="/#/create" access="admin"
```

and

```
security:intercept-url pattern="/#/view/**" access="admin"
```

when tried accessing the url `//localhost:8080/server/#/create` with role different from admin (Eg. User), I am stil able to access this page whereas any URLs like `//localhost:8080/server/abc/create` shows as `Access Denied` when i change the url pattern accordingly.

Is that the `#` in the URL will be neglected and is there any other way through which i can solve this problem ?

Comment: Which is as expected and how http works. Everything after the # isn't submitted to the server. The # is basically an anchor and only for the client. That is just how the web works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, either you implement the security layer on front end (angularjs) or backend (spring security).

For angular js, you can use a plugin to provide security in each route by checking the user authorities provided by the backend after successful authentication. Such plugin can be easily customized such as what this blog explained
[angular-role-base-auth](http://arthur.gonigberg.com/2013/06/29/angularjs-role-based-auth)

or another one here

[angular-permission](https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission)

But I suggest to still implement security layer in the backend since javascript code can easily be hacked via browser console. In spring security, you can add permission check on webservices called by those pages and return access denied. Then in you front end, once you encounter an access denied response, redirect the page to a custom page displaying forbidden message template.